# ASP.NET Repeater - Eval() for bool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a simple repeater, where I want to display checked/unchecked checkboxes:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <td>
         <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb" Checked='<%# Eval("value") %>' />
      </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>


var list = new List<bool>();

list.Add(true);
list.Add(false);

myRepeater.DataSource = list;
myRepeater.DataBind();
```

but I get an error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Boolean' does not contain a property with the
>   name 'value'.

How to fix it ?

Comment: is "value" the name of the boolean field your biding?

Comment: @JuanC. that List contains only raw bool values, without any properties/fields.

Comment: use <%# Container.DataItem %> instead of Eval

Comment: try with just this <%# Container.DataItem %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <td>
         <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb" Checked='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
      </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Eval(x) is a shortcut for Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, x).  Which evalutes the property/etc x for the row item in the repeater.  But you don't need to evaluate anything, you just want the raw DataItem.